# Django sending template variable to form

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to assign javascript variable to django variable and assign this variable to form.

In template/html, I try to assign one_card (js variable) to my_password (django variable) :

```
    {% load set_var %}
    {% load assign_node %}
    {% set {{ my_password }} = one_card %}
```

In form.py, my_password doesn't recognized:

```
  from django import forms
  from .models import Signup


  class sign_up_form(forms.ModelForm):
      password=forms.CharField(initial=my_password)

      class Meta: 
              model = Signup   
              widgets = { 'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
                       }
```

In view.py:

```
  def home(request):
         form = sign_up_form(request.POST or None)
```

Problem is I cannot assing template variable to django variable and I cannot assign this variable to form because django say it doesn't exist.

I have tried for 1 day, thanks for helping.

Comment: That's not even valid Django template syntax.

Comment: I know but it become too messy and i'm new, but it is short to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript....

```
function change_password() {
    document.getElementById('#id_password')
    // or jquery $('#id_password').val(one_card);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to put this into django form to record.

Comment: id_password should be a field of the form.